# Dependent mutation React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm using React Query to make requests in a React Native mobile application. I want to register a user when the login request returns a 404 error. I've done this as follows using a recursive useCallback.

The second registration user request is executed correctly, but the recursive handleLogin call doesn't work.

```js
    const { mutate: login } = useLogin()
    const { mutate: register } = useRegister()
    const internalQueryClient = useQueryClient()

    const handleLogin = useCallback(async () => {
        const installationID = await getInstallationId()
        login(
            { deviceId: installationID },
            {
                onSuccess: (loginResult) => {
                    saveAccessToken(loginResult)
                },
                onError: (error) => {
                    if (error.response?.status === HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
                        register(
                            {
                                deviceInfos: {
                                    deviceId: installationID,
                                    platform: Platform.OS.toUpperCase(),
                                    appBuildNumber: getBuildNumber(),
                                },
                                subscription: {
                                    packageSubscribe: 'NONE',
                                    lastPaymentDate: null,
                                    paymentDeadline: null,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                onSettled: async () => {
                                    await internalQueryClient.invalidateQueries({
                                        queryKey: [QueryUrl.auth.login],
                                    })
                                    await handleLogin()
                                },
                            },
                        )
                    }
                },
            },
        )
    }, [login, register])

    useEffect(() => {
        const init = async (): Promise<void> => {
            await handleLogin()
        }

        init().then()
    }, [])
```

How can I re-run the handleLogin function once the register mutation has been successfully executed?

Answer (score 1):

To re-run the handleLogin function after the register mutation has been successfully executed, you can use React Query's `onSettled` hook within the onSuccess callback of the register mutation. This will trigger a refetch of the `QueryUrl.auth.login` query when the register mutation successfully completes.

Here's the modified code:

```
const { mutate: login } = useLogin()
const { mutate: register } = useRegister()
const internalQueryClient = useQueryClient()

const handleLogin = useCallback(async () => {
const installationID = await getInstallationId()
login(
  { deviceId: installationID },
   {
   onSuccess: (loginResult) => {
    saveAccessToken(loginResult)
  },
  onError: (error) => {
    if (error.response?.status === HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
      register(
        {
          deviceInfos: {
            deviceId: installationID,
            platform: Platform.OS.toUpperCase(),
            appBuildNumber: getBuildNumber(),
          },
          subscription: {
            packageSubscribe: 'NONE',
            lastPaymentDate: null,
            paymentDeadline: null,
          },
        },
        {
          onSettled: async () => {
            // Trigger another refetch of the login query
            await internalQueryClient.invalidateQueries({
              queryKey: [QueryUrl.auth.login],
            })
            // Re-run the login
            await handleLogin()
          },
        },
      )
    }
  },
},
)
}, [login, register])

useEffect(() => {
  const init = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await handleLogin()
}

init().then()
}, [])
```

This approach will ensure that the `handleLogin` function is re-executed after the register mutation is completed, effectively retrying the login attempt.